# Import causes image to lose resolution

Tags: image-processing, image

I am having trouble preserving image resolutions in Mathematica 13.0.1.

The following is [a free high-resolution GIF from Giphy dot com](https://giphy.com/gifs/artists-on-tumblr-design-V0K6lmtLOz2LK), pasted below for your convenience:

[image]

I notice that even if I simply import the image and run `ListAnimation` on it, the result is a low-resolution image that looks quite un-smooth:

```
"high-res-gif.gif" // (Import /* ListAnimate)
```

I have tried setting `ImageResolution` to 127--I have a 17-inch laptop with a resolution of 1920 by 1080--but the result is still a much grainier image than the original.

**EDIT**

[This link](https://github.com/Shredderroy/tmp-repo/blob/main/high-res-gif-2-2.gif) shows what the imported image in Mathematica looks like. I cannot post the image here because it exceeds the 2 MB limit.

It is very easy to see that the imported version of the image is of a much lower quality.

I have tried Chris Degnen's suggestion in the answer below. The following is a snapshot of the image quality:

[image]

It is quite easy to see the degradation in image quality.

**END EDIT**

Is there a specific trick to importing high resolution images?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a loss of resolution, they are being stretch filled.  That means new pixels need to be synthesized to fill in the missing ones.  You can control that method using a (currently undocumented in 13.0) option to `RasterBox`.

`Style[ListAnimate[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNjgV.gif"], BaseStyle -> {"RasterBoxOptions" -> {"SmoothingQuality" -> "High"}}]]`

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I was looking for. I wish Wolfram Research's documentation made these points clearer.

Answer (score 1):

The Giphy page says the image is 500 x 500

[image]

And the image you're displaying is the same.

```
frame1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNjgV.gif"][[1]];
ImageDimensions[frame1]
```

> {500, 500}

Comment: I am not sure you read the question closely before posting the response. The image displayed in the original post is exactly the image from Giphy. My point is that when that same image is imported into Mathematica, the quality is lost.

I have edited the post to include a link to the imported image. (I cannot post the imported image since it is bigger than 2 MB in size.)

Comment: `ListAnimate[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNjgV.gif"]]` looks fine on Mathematica 13.0.0.  Try `ListAnimate[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNjgV.gif"], ImageSize -> 500]`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about `ImageSize`. I tried your exact command as above. Please see the edited question for the image quality that I observe.

Comment: ImageSize->{500, 500} is rarely equivalent to ImageDimensions[frame1].  They use two different units.